# current-menu-item not added on page showing custom post type (rendered with archive template)

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-post-type-archives

1. I have setup a custom post type called 'expertizeom'

   1. I have setup a page called "expertize" and added to my custom menu
      (site main nav).
   2. The page is rendered with an archive called archive-expertizeom.php

The problem is that when i browse to that page everything is working fine but **wordpress isn't
adding the current-menu-item class**.

can you help?
Thanks

Francesco

Comment: I ran into this problem a while back and found this tutorial useful -
http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/theme-development/add-post-type-archive-links-to-your-menu/ It walks through creating a plugin to add a meta box for adding custom post type archives to the menu and solves the current-menu-item issue.
(the link to the complete plugin is down the bottom if you're after a quick fix)

Answer (score 2):

If you using [wp nav menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) you can use this to add the current-menu-item class put this in your theme functions.php file and **remember to change "mypageslug" to your wanted current page**:

```
function additional_active_item_classes($classes = array(), $menu_item = false){
    global $wp_query;

    if ( $menu_item->post_name == 'mypageslug' && is_page_template('archive-expertizeom.php') ) {
        $classes[] = 'current-menu-item';
    }

    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'additional_active_item_classes', 10, 2 );
```

This Code adds the class "current-page-item" if you are on a page with the `template archive-expertizeom.php` and the menu have a post_name that matches the post_name "mypageslug ie the slug of the wanted page.

Comment: Thankyou very much for the response but it is not working I've found another solution in the menawhile http://www.rarescosma.com/2010/11/add-a-class-to-wp_nav_menu-items-with-urls-included-in-the-current-url/

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i'm using magic-fields-2 plugin to create custom post types - i had just to activate the option "Hierarchical -
Whether the post type is hierarchical. Allows Parent to be specified"

Comment: How does this answers the Question?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem and this worked for me:

```
query_posts('cat=3');
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
```

`wp_reset_query();` does all the magic :)

Comment: How do you know the asker used `query_posts()`? Most devs [don't do that anymore](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts). :)

Answer (score 0):

@pontus-abrahamsson's answer didn't quite work for me as my pages were using page.php and so I needed something else to determine whether it was the same page I was viewing.

I don't know how robust this is but it worked for me and it works with all templates (that I tried):

```php
function additional_active_item_classes($classes = array(), $menu_item = false){
    global $wp;
    global $wp_query;

    if ( home_url( $wp->request ) == rtrim($menu_item->url,"/") ) {
        $classes[] = 'current-menu-item';
    }

    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'additional_active_item_classes', 10, 2 );
```